# Assigning a new data point to a cluster in hierarchical clustering

Tags: matlab, hierarchical-clustering

I have clustered my data X with hierarchical clustering in the following way:

```
Y = pdist(X);
Z = linkage(Y);
T = cluster(Z,'maxclust',2);
```

How can I determine to which cluster a new data point (not in X) should be assigned to? For k-means one can just assign the data point to the cluster with the nearest centroid but for hierarchical clustering I don't see how to do it.

Comment: if you want to maintain the correct linkage then you probably have to start again from scratch. Even if you are using one of the linkage options that only depends on one of the values in each group  (e.g. `complete` or `single`), your new point might - at certain points in the hierarchy - be that one point for its group, and will thus change the next steps in the linkage.

Comment: @dan-man Thanks for your answer. Would it be a possibility to first use hierarchical clustering for finding the best number of clusters and then applying k-means? If yes, how can I find the best number of clusters with hiearchical clustering?